# Windows Server 2012 Failover DHCP

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp, dhcp-server, failovercluster

I've been tasked with migrating from our current 50/50 scope resilient DHCP servers to new hot standby failover DHCP in Server 2012 R2.

Built a test bed with the two DHCP server VMs and created a failover relationship between them.

Created a few desktop OS VMs and confirmed that the hot standby failover is working well.

Next I manually created an address reservation on one of the servers, but that reservation did not appear on the other after waiting the specified time.

I know I can just right click the scope and replicate it, but I would prefer an automatic one to one relationship between the servers e.g what is created on one is automatically represented on the other.

It works like this with address leases so would expect the same with reservations.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scope options and reservations are not replicated automatically. See [this comment](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/teamdhcp/2012/08/06/dhcp-failover-load-balance-mode/#comment-7831) from "Microsoft Windows DNS, DHCP and IPAM Team Blog".

There is a Powershell Cmdlet in Server 2012R2:

`Invoke–DhcpServerv4FailoverReplication –ComputerName dhcpserver.contoso.com`

This will

> replicate all of the failover scopes on the DHCP server service
>   running on the computer named dhcpserver.contoso.com to one or more
>   respective partner DHCP server services based on one or more failover
>   relationships in which the DHCP server services are included.

See [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590740)

This can be automated with Task Planner.
The downside is that a replication will fully overwrite the DHCP configs of your other server (it is not a sync).